# Changing chapter style affecting Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, chapters

I am changing style for my chapter and in turn it is affecting the Table of Contents title.

This is my table of contents page:

[image]

and this is my chapter page:

[image]

This is the code snippet:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\fontsize{16}{18}\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}
{1em}
{}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{0pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\flushright\fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}{\fontseries{b}\fontsize{72}{84}\selectfont\textcolor{black}\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}
{.\\ \Huge\bfseries}
[]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{540pt}{20pt}
```

Comment: Okay... so what do you want the format of the ToC chapter to look like then?

Comment: Same as the default ..

Comment: Then move the titleformat and titlespacing commands to after the ToC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\titleformat` updates how the `\chapter` is set at the time you call it. So, if you want to delay the chapter formatting, just delay the call to `\titleformat`:

```
% ...
\usepackage{titlesec}
% ...

\chapter{A chapter}% Default formatting for \chapter

% ...

\titleformat{\chapter}% ...

\chapter{Another chapter}% New/updated formatting for \chapter

% ...
```